# Restart Apache causes applications to react really weird

Tags: keyboard, high-sierra, apache

I have macOS High Sierra running on my Mac, and it has worked fine until now. But today I experienced something very weird. I was trying to restart Apache (a web development server), and then my apps started reacting very weird. For example, I had Activity Monitor open, and then suddenly it crashed and when I tried to open it again, it either says "Activity Monitor is not open anymore." or just doesn't respond. And when I try to use Command Tab to switch to another app, it just gives me the sound that tells me that you cannot do that, and the same with Command Q and Command W. Not many of my apps are willing to open when I try to open them. After a while my keyboard even doesn't react when I type!

If I restart my computer, it is working fine in the start but when I try to restart Apache, it does all that crab again.

UPDATE: If I have an app that is not responding, lets say the Terminal, and I go to the menu bar and click Terminal > Quit Terminal, then suddenly the menu bar disappears.

What can I do to fix my computer?

Comment: Start off by booting into Safe Mode (hold Shift while booting)  then test out to see if the symptoms persist.

Comment: I just ran into this problem myself with Mojave trying to run Apache. Did you ever find out the cause/solution?

Comment: I don't really remember if it fixed itself after some updates or something, but have you tried the suggestion by @Allan?

Comment: @HiramHibbard Check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a somewhat working solution.

I am using Homebrew's httpd package, so I found out that I could just reinstall it:

1. When it begins to do that weird stuff, restart the computer.
2. Then reinstall httpd with `brew reinstall httpd`
3. You're good!

EDIT:

I later found out that it was an issue with the MySQL server that was not running/having a problem.

Comment: Instead of using homebrews apache, you could also stick with the defult provided by MacOS.

Comment: The reason I do this is because I used [this](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-mojave-apache-multiple-php-versions) guide, which uses Homebrew's Apache instead of the native apache.